# Invalid space characters when copying code from powerpoint to vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, character-encoding, powerpoint

When I copy code from a textbox in PowerPoint to VS Code, the latter complains about bad characters in the lines' indentation:

[image]

When hovering the mouse on the problematic places, it shows that the characters are "\ua0" and "U+000b".

I have to manually delete and reenter the indentation to fix the code. Why does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check the character. I assume PowerPoint use a lot the non-breaking space (instead of the expected "space character"), for reasons (PP works often with variable width fonts, and spaces are often not so relevant (but the existence, see also HTML). Programming uses spaces to fill a cell with a characters without any "black" part).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The code was originally copied to PP from VS Code...

Comment: But PP will change it. All WYSIWYG things is about getting a good visual representation, not to keep the data. In past it was not uncommon to get also some formatting characters (or delimiters, in Unicode reserved part) back into the code.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi In PP, they show as spaces (I can walk the indentation by pressing the right arrow of the keyboard four times).

Comment: Could you copy the code (or the spaces) in the question? If you copy in an code editor and it doesn't see as spaces, probably they are not the usual `SP` (ASCII 0x20). There are many other spaces (e.g. "Windows ANSI" has the non breaking space, and Unicode has additional ones). U+00A0 is the non breaking space

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi When I grab the text from PP, SO thinks I am pasting an image...

Comment: Note: Possibly SuperUser (link on top right icon) may be more appropriate for your question. When you copy things in Windows, different version of the copy will be put in clipboard. Your browser need to decide which version is better, and in this case it will select an image (and in a specific format). It is possible that some control character will confuse the browser. In any case, I think you should go to SuperUser and get how PowerPoint formatting and clipboard work. After you learn it, probably you can solve the programming side, or just ask here again.